# Porting from Tomcat to Jetty9 for Heroku hosting

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, heroku, jetty

We have a Tomcat 7 application, using Mongo on the back end, JSF, and HTML5 on the front end, running on Cloudbees, that we have to move to a new hosting service.

We are considering porting to Jetty 9 (for Websocket and SPDY support) and hosting on Heroku.

Are there any gotchas, best practices, or suggestions for porting this type of application to Jetty9? Any issues with Jetty 9 for a production app, or Heroku for hosting? Alternative suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: As long as you don't use the default servlet explicitly, there shouldn't be a problem. Other than that, I don't see a problem. However, an easy check would be to deploy your app into a local jetty and run your integration tests against this setup

Comment: Keep in mind you can also still use Tomcat, via the `webapp-runner` project. See https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner. Probably the biggest lift in porting to Heroku, which applies to both Tomcat and Jetty, is configuration for "containerless" deployment and ensuring that your app scales properly (e.g., Redis or Memcache for session storage, since there is no session affinity or session replication in Heroku.

Comment: Also note that available protocols will actually be constrained by the Heroku routing layer. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing. There is currently support for Websockets but not SPDY.